# "dd" an image onto an sd-card from Ubuntu in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, dd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a bootable disk image file that I'd like to write onto an sd-card.  However, I only have a Windows 10 machine available - it has the Windows Subsystem for Linux already installed, Ubuntu runs, and `dd` is available.

I'd like to do `sudo dd if=image.img of=/dev/my-sd-card`, however the sd-card device does not appear in `/dev`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't believe WSL exposes direct device access like that. It's all a simulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use Rufus when performing this type of operation on a Windows machine.  This program is great for creating bootable media, particularly when using Linux images.  Also, the "DD" function works really well.

This software is free and open source.

If you insist on using your Ubuntu subsystem, type the command "tail -f /var/log/syslog" or "dmesg -w" then connect the mmc.  This will display where it has been made available in userspace, and will be a good troubleshooting step should nothing happen.  You may not have these commands available depending on how Ubuntu is configured.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine using a GUI tool, you could use etcher: https://etcher.io/

A free, open-source, and **cross-platform** (ie. native Windows build) image burning tool that can burn images to SD cards and USB devices.

Very simple to use, first download it for Windows (the option is there for a portable exe if you prefer it.)
[image]

Install and run the software, then choose your image file
[image]

[image]

Select your USB device
[image]
[image]

Click "Flash!", and then wait.
[image]

Comment: Aren't those are Mac images and icons?

Comment: wow, since when should a simple single-function tool be 270+MB, and for the *portable* version!

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Some parts of the UI, yes, but the the tool is for Windows as well, and the only difference is the UI. The part where you choose an image is the same process as on Mac, or even Linux.

Comment: @MaxVernon I know, I know, but it's too much for me to remember "sudo dd bs=1M if=my_iso_file of=/dev/rdisk4s2" when I repeatedly burn ISO images for my Raspberry Pi